# Binding Grouped data to UITableview in Xamarin using Mvvmcross

Tags: ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am trying to bind grouped data to a table, but when I run the code the binding seems to be trying to create a cell for the Section level items rather than creating a section with the cells behind it.

First, I create my table:

```
    table = new UITableView(CGRect.Empty, UITableViewStyle.Grouped);
    table.RowHeight = UxConstants.UiDimensions.Dimension48;
    table.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.All;
    table.ScrollEnabled = true;
```

then I create my view source and bind it:

```
var source = new OperationalInfoTableViewSource(table);
        table.Source = source;

        var set = this.CreateBindingSet<IncidentInformationView, IncidentInformationViewModel>();
        set.Bind(source).For(vm => vm.ItemsSource).To(vm => vm.TableSourceItem);
        set.Apply();
```

I'm using a simplified class at the moment; so the binding target (TableSourceItem) is currently  defined as:

```
public ObservableCollection<Stuff> TableSourceItem
{
    get
    {
        return tableSourceItem;
    }

    set
    {
        tableSourceItem = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => TableSourceItem);
    }
}
```

and the 'Stuff' class is simply

```
public class Stuff
{
    public string Title {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public List<string> Items {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

When I declare my data :

```
        var items = new List<Stuff>();
        items.Add(new Stuff { Title = "Group 1", Items = new List<string> { "Item 1", "Item 2" } });
        items.Add(new Stuff { Title = "Group 2", Items = new List<string> { "Item 4", "Item 5"} });
        TableSourceItem = new ObservableCollection<Stuff>(items);
```

The final bit of Code, is the table view source I have defined.  This inherits from the MvxStandardTableView source:

```
    public class OperationalInfoTableViewSource : MvxStandardTableViewSource
    {
        List<Stuff> items;

        public OperationalInfoTableViewSource(UITableView tableView) : base (tableView)


   {
        TableView.RegisterClassForCellReuse (typeof(OperationalInfoViewCell), OperationalInfoViewCell.Key);
    }

    public override System.Collections.IEnumerable ItemsSource
    {
        get
        {
            return items;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                items = new List<Stuff>();
                foreach (Stuff item in value)
                {
                    items.Add(item);
                }

                base.ItemsSource = items;
            }
        }
    }

    public override string TitleForHeader(UITableView tableView, nint section)
    {
        return "Header";
    }

    public override nint NumberOfSections(UITableView tableView)
    {
        var i = items == null ? 0 : items.Count();

        Mvx.Trace(String.Format( "Number of Sections {0}",  i ));
        return i;
    }

    public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, nint section)
    {
        return items == null ? 0 : items[(int)section].Items.Count();
    }

    public override bool CanEditRow(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public override bool CanPerformAction(UITableView tableView, ObjCRuntime.Selector action, NSIndexPath indexPath, NSObject sender)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public override bool CanMoveRow(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        return false;
    }       

    protected override UITableViewCell GetOrCreateCellFor(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath, object item)
    {
        var cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(OperationalInfoViewCell.Key);             

        return cell;
    }

    public override nfloat GetHeightForHeader(UITableView tableView, nint section)
    {
        return UxConstants.UiDimensions.Dimension32;
    }

    public override UIView GetViewForHeader(UITableView tableView, nint section)
    {
        var operationalInfoTitle = new UILabel()
        {
            Lines = 1,
            Font = UxConstants.UxFonts.MediumBold,
            TextColor = UxConstants.UxColours.BBlue,
            Text = "Guidance & Info"
        };

        var operationalInfoTitleDivider = new UIView()
        { 
            BackgroundColor = UxConstants.UxColours.MGrey 
        };

        var operationalInfoListView = new UIView();

        operationalInfoListView.AddSubviews(operationalInfoTitle, operationalInfoTitleDivider);
        operationalInfoListView.SubviewsDoNotTranslateAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints();

        operationalInfoListView.AddConstraints(operationalInfoTitle.FullWidthOf(operationalInfoListView, UxConstants.UiDimensions.Dimension16));
        operationalInfoListView.AddConstraints(operationalInfoTitleDivider.FullWidthOf(operationalInfoListView, UxConstants.UiDimensions.Dimension16));

        operationalInfoListView.AddConstraints(
            operationalInfoTitle.Height().EqualTo(UxConstants.UiDimensions.Dimension32),
            operationalInfoTitle.AtTopOf(operationalInfoListView),
            operationalInfoTitleDivider.Below(operationalInfoTitle),
            operationalInfoTitleDivider.Height().EqualTo(2));

        return operationalInfoListView;
    }
}
```

I would expect 2 sections, each with two cells, but its seems to be creating one cell per `Stuff` class rather than one section per `Stuff` class.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found out the issue, I have failed to implement the important override:

```
protected override object GetItemAt(NSIndexPath indexPath)
{

    if (items == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    return  items[indexPath.Section].Items.ElementAt((int)indexPath.Item);
}
```

Once I had included this method override it worked fine!